# Shopify Billing API after OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

After I complete OAuth how do I immediately redirect to my recurring charges controller, so I can initiate a charge request with the user? It would be a POST request to my charges controller. The documentation was not any help! I'm guessing it has something to do with redirecting after authentication, but since this is a post request to a controller is that even possible? My app is built on the Shopify Gem using code from Link 2.

[Sample Code from Github Using Sinatra on Charge Controllers](https://github.com/Shopify/example-ruby-app/blob/master/02%20Charging%20For%20Your%20App/app.rb)

[Session Controller from Shopify Gem App Skeleton](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/app/controllers/shopify_app/sessions_controller.rb)